# What's the defined_classes in a Java thread dump?

Tags: java, thread-dump

Rinning `jstack -e` produces a dump like this (at least in Java 19):

> "Thread-0" #25 [23276] prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=593.30s allocated=6720B defined_classes=1 tid=0x0000023dafe60b20 nid=23276 waiting for monitor entry  [0x000000796a4ff000]

What does "defined_classes" mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This output is coming from the enhancement [JDK-8200720](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8200720). Its implementation defines this values as follow:

> - defined_classes=... : The number of classes defined by this thread
>
> This might hint to a thread that loads too many classes.

It was added in commit [d1b24f2ceca5](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/d1b24f2ceca5) on 25 Jun 2018.

Answer (score 0):

This attribute gives the number of classes defined by this thread.